# Style disappears in secondary pages

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

In my reactjs app I have the Routs as below

```
function App() {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Router>
          <MenuBar />
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/Jobs" component={Jobs} />
          <Route exact path="/CreatePost" component={CreatePost} />
          <Route exact path="/CreatePost/NewPage" component={NewPage} />
      </Router>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

For all pages that are primary like Home and Jobs the style is correct,however if I go to a nested page **CreatePost/NewPage** or another one **FirstPage/SecondPage** the style gets removed....

I am working on a **bootstrap theme** and have included the JS libraries in my index.html file.
Please let me know why the following happens

**UPDATE**

the styles are include in index.html public folder like this:

```
   <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/libs/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css"/>

  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root" ></div>
    
    <script src="assets/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/libs/svg-injector/dist/svg-injector.min.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I suggest you improve your question, add some examples, some code and make it more clear and add your source code, Have a look here => [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @FedericoBaù I just did it,please take a loook

Comment: @kiranvj please take another look,just updated it

Comment: @BruceWayne Great, this seems better, I don't know the answer my self but this would certanly help you get one soon hopefully

Comment: Hey there, can you try to move your styling scripts above the root declaration?

Comment: @qslabs just tried, unfortunately still the same...smh the error says Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'...and its leading to `<!DOCTYPE html>` which doesnt make any sense

Comment: @BruceWayne It it worked you should marked  kiranvj as accepted answer so the question is out of answered queue thanks

Comment: @FedericoBaù absolutely I know,I just was a little busy ,but thanks for reminding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `/` prefix to the path names so that the files will always load from root.

Add `/` before `assets`

Example `/assets/libs/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css`